# How to make all content in a linear layout be one clickable item

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a link in android with a linear layout as the main view. within that there will be a horizontal linear layout for each row, in each row there will be an image and a description and a price and a id(wont be displayed).

Once i have a list off all my items i want the user to be able to click any where on the row and it will then do some action. How can i do this?  I have tried settings clickable=true on the linearlayout:

here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:onClick="menuItemSelected" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/burger" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="This a pictuer of a hamburger" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="R41.24" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="menuItemSelected" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Product Image"
        android:src="@drawable/burger" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="This a pictuer of a hamburger" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="R41.24" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is that not the same as the `onClick="MenuItemSelected"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want a custom ListView: [How to make custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308015/how-to-make-custom-listview)

This will allow you to create a scrollable, clickable, table of content. By customizing it you can format the content any way you'd like for each row.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is best done using a ListView: [ListView Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)

You should create a ListView, an Adapter and a custom View for that. By doing that you will be able to have the OnListItemClickedListener from which you can obtain not only the id of your list item, but the item itself.